# Ubuntu 15.04 freezes before installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 15.04

I just installed Windows 8.1 on one partition and wanted to install Ubuntu 15.04 on another one. I burned the latest Ubuntu ISO and after rebooting my laptop, it started loading (I had the logo and white/red dots). However, after some time computer freezed (I think) - it got quiet (no sound of reading disc) and the dots stopped changing colours (three of them are still red and two are white).

I'm not using UEFI.

Should I try installing older version or do something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test the ISO after you burned it? I've had symptoms like this before with poor quality CD-R's/DVD-R's

I would try burning a new disc or use good old [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and install from a USB stick